# Interruptible thread example in 《C++ Concurrency In Action》

Tags: c++, multithreading, interrupt

《C++ Concurrency In Action》 implements an interruptible thread in `Chapter 9.2 Interrupting thread`. `Listing 9.10` is below:

```
void interruptible_wait(std::condition_variable& cv,
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lk)
{
    interruption_point();
    this_thread_interrupt_flag.set_condition_variable(cv);
    cv.wait(lk);
    this_thread_interrupt_flag.clear_condition_variable();
    interruption_point();
}
```

According to the book, this function introduces the problem below:

> If the thread is interrupted after the initial call to interruption_point(), but before the call to wait(), then it doesn’t matter whether the condition variable has been associated with the interrupt flag, because the thread isn’t waiting and so can’t be woken by a notify on the condition variable. **You need to ensure** that the thread can’t be notified between the last check for interruption and the call to wait().

**The first question** is why we `need to ensure that`? 'Cause this function seems to run correctly even `the thread is interrupted after the initial call to interruption_point() and before the call to wait()`. Could anyone tell me how this function will go south? Is it because cv.wait(lk) will never be notified under this situation?

**The second question** is how `Listing 9.11` solve this problem the book mentions just by replacing `cv.wait()` by `cv.wait_for()`:

```
void interruptible_wait(std::condition_variable& cv,
                        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& lk)
{
    interruption_point();
    this_thread_interrupt_flag.set_condition_variable(cv);
    interrupt_flag::clear_cv_on_destruct guard;
    interruption_point();
    cv.wait_for(lk,std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    interruption_point();
}
```

Comment: love your brackets :*

Answer (score 2):

1. If the other thread calls `notify()` before this thread gets to `wait()`, this thread won't receive that notification, and will wait forever for another one.
2. `wait_for` doesn't wait forever.

Comment: Thank you. Did I misunderstand the word `ensure` in the book? Does it mean "understand" instead of "guarantee"?

Comment: @StephenW No, in this context it means "guarantee". The wording's a little weird, though... a better wording would be "you need to ensure that *the expected notification does not occur* between the last check for interruption and the call to `wait()`".

Comment: Well, then why do we need to ensure that? If the other thread calls `notify_all()` or `notify_one()` before this thread gets to`wait()`, I think it's **natural** that there is no more notification will occur between the last check for interruption and the call to `wait()`. It seems that there is **nothing we have to do/ensure** about this. What we only have to do is using `wait_for()` to replace the `wait()` as you suggested.

Comment: @StephenW  does it also mean: you need to ensure that the expected notification  occur between the first check for interruption and the call to wait()